# Overlapping Text in Animation in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm making Terror Attacks analysis using Python. And I wanted make an animation. I made it but I have a problem the text above the animation overlaps in every frame. How can I fix it?

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (7,4))
def animate(Year):
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.clear()
    ax.set_title('Terrorism In Turkey\n'+ str(Year))
    m5 = Basemap(projection='lcc',resolution='l' ,width=1800000, height=900000 ,lat_0=38.9637, lon_0=35.2433)
    lat_gif=list(terror_turkey[terror_turkey['Year']==Year].Latitude)
    long_gif=list(terror_turkey[terror_turkey['Year']==Year].Longitude)
    x_gif,y_gif=m5(long_gif,lat_gif)
    m5.scatter(x_gif, y_gif,s=[Death+Injured for Death,Injured in zip(terror_turkey[terror_turkey['Year']==Year].Death,terror_turkey[terror_turkey['Year']==Year].Injured)],color = 'r')
    m5.drawcoastlines()
    m5.drawcountries()
    m5.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua', zorder = 1,alpha=0.4)
    m5.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, list(terror_turkey.Year.unique()), interval = 1500) 

ani.save('animation_tr.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=1)
plt.close(1)
filename = 'animation_tr.gif'
video = io.open(filename, 'r+b').read()
encoded = base64.b64encode(video)
HTML(data='''<img src="data:image/gif;base64,{0}" type="gif" />'''.format(encoded.decode('ascii')))
```

Output:

[image: Output:]

Comment: Did you consider creating the axes the usual way, as in `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (7,4))` (in the main code, not inside the `animate` function)? And leaving out the call to `plt.axes()`?

Comment: @JohanC Can you write your comment as an answer? I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohanC's recommendation in comments resolved my problem:

> Did you consider creating the axes the usual way, as in `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (7,4))` (in the main code, not inside the animate function)? And leaving out the call to `plt.axes()?`